# Waiting For Home ('android.process.acore') to be launched

Tags: android, emulation

Can u help me for this.. i have been waiting for 2 hours or more, then Emulator will start.. Guys two hours is too more.. how to solve that..??

i found a solution in same site like: "if u get this message then again right click on project and start again you will get another emulator and it will work.." - But that Emulator also take half an hour or more to start application..

So anybody have any fast solution that emulator start within 5 to max 10 min..!!

Help me for this plz......

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1554099/1321873

Answer (score 0):

2h is too long, it should take max. 5mins. Tried it with wiping user data and not to launch it from snapshot? What API are you using? How is it configured?

Comment: Hello Staaar, Sorry for late reply.. was stuck with other works.. and yes using Google API [level 16], not with snapshot[not enabled] and and without wipe user data[its unchecked]..!! so what changes should i make to work it fast..?? any suggestions..??

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Android SDK tools directory in Command Prompt

   1. type adb kill-server
   2. then type adb start-server
   3. No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then adb is started successfully.